# factorization of a unit of an adjunction

Tags: category-theory, adjoint-functors

Let $F$ be a left adjoint functor to $V$.
Factor $X \to VK$ through the adjunction unit
$$
X \to VFX \to VK,
$$
where the first map is $\eta_X$, the second map is $V$ of the adjoint map $FX \to K$, the composite is the given $X \to VK$. Why?

Answer (score 1):

This follows from naturality of $\eta$ and one of the triangle identities: the adjoint of $f : X \to VK$ is $\bar f := \varepsilon_K \circ F(f) : FX \to K$, and so you have
$$V(\bar f) \circ \eta_X = V(\varepsilon_K) \circ VF(f) \circ \eta_X \overset{\text{naturality}}{=} V(\varepsilon_K) \circ \eta_{VK} \circ f \overset{\text{triangle}}{=} f$$